# Extraction of matched dataset from MatchThem

Tags: matching, r-mice, propensity-score-matching

I have browsed almost all possible pages on the subject and I still can't find a way to extract a matched data dataset with the MatchThem package.
By analogy, MatchIt allows via the function match.data() to extract the dataset of matched data for example 3:1. Although MatchThem's complete() function is the equivalent, this function apparently does not allow to extract exclusively the imputed AND matched dataset.

Here is an example of multiple imputation with 3:1 matching from which I am trying to extract multiple matched datasets:

```
library(mice)
library(MatchThem)

#Multiple imputations
mids_object <- mice(data, maxit = 5, m=3, seed= 20211022, printFlag = F) # m=3 is voluntarily low for this example.

#Matching
mimids_object <- matchthem(primary_subtype ~ age + bmi + ps, data = mids_object, approach = "within" ,ratio= 3, method = "optimal")

#Details of matched data
print(mimids_object)
```

Printing | dataset: #1
A matchit object

- method: Variable ratio 3:1 optimal pair matching
- distance: Propensity score
  - estimated with logistic regression
- number of obs: 761 (original), 177 (matched)
- target estimand: ATT
- covariates: age, bmi, ps

  #Extracting matched dataset
  complete(mimids_object, action = "long") -> complete_mi_matched

  #Summary of extracted dataset to check correct number of match
  summary(complete_mi_matched$primary_subtype)

classic ADK SRC
702 59

It should show the matched proportion 3:1 with 177 matched (177 classic ADK and 59 SRC)

I am missing something. Thanks in advance for your help or suggestions.

Comment: Why does `complete(mimids_object, 1)` not work for you? If you only want units with weights greater than 0, have you tired setting `all = FALSE`? I'm not exactly sure what you want that isn't covered in the documentation for `complete.mimids()`.

Comment: Many thanks Noah for your help! Your solution is just right to the point. That's what I missed. The dataset extracted is exactly as I wanted (matched 3:1).